# dynamically generated thymeleaf input with javascript and send its value to the controller is not working

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table with rows with th:fields, everything works OK.
I need to add new rows, so I did it with javascript but when I submit the form those new rows are not submited. Do I need a special magic for that?

```
th:field="*{configuredProperties[__${iterator.index}__].propertyType}"
```

Thanks!

edited:
I create a row like this:

```
function addProperty() {
        var rows = $('#propertiesTable tbody tr');
        var row = rows[0];
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true);

        clone.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = null;
        clone.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value = null;
        clone.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].value = null;

        var lastRow = rows[rows.length - 1];
        var newId = parseInt(lastRow.getAttribute("id")) + 1;
        clone.id = newId;

        var link = $(clone).find('#removeProperty')[0];
        link.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeProperty(' + newId + ')');


        var propertyType = $(clone).find('#propertyType')[0];
        propertyType.setAttribute('name', '*{configuredProperties[' + newId + '].propertyType');
        var propertyName = $(clone).find('#propertyName')[0];
        propertyName.setAttribute('name', '*{configuredProperties[' + newId + '].propertyName');
        var defaultValue = $(clone).find('#defaultValue')[0];
        defaultValue.setAttribute('name', '*{configuredProperties[' + newId + '].defaultValue');    

        var tbody = $('#propertiesTable tbody')[0];
        tbody.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Comment: can you post your javascript code? The one that adds the row.

Comment: Hi @Aboodz , I add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

in this block you need to provide the name of your bean field

```
   var propertyType = $(clone).find('#propertyType')[0];
    propertyType.setAttribute('name', '*{configuredProperties[' + newId + '].propertyType');
    var propertyName = $(clone).find('#propertyName')[0];
    propertyName.setAttribute('name', '*{configuredProperties[' + newId + '].propertyName');
    var defaultValue = $(clone).find('#defaultValue')[0];
    defaultValue.setAttribute('name', '*{configuredProperties[' + newId + '].defaultValue');
```

by constructing the field like so

```
   var propertyType = $(clone).find('#propertyType')[0];
    propertyType.setAttribute('name', 'configuredProperties[' + newId + '].propertyType');
    var propertyName = $(clone).find('#propertyName')[0];
    propertyName.setAttribute('name', 'configuredProperties[' + newId + '].propertyName');
    var defaultValue = $(clone).find('#defaultValue')[0];
    defaultValue.setAttribute('name', 'configuredProperties[' + newId + '].defaultValue');
```